# Entry in table of content and page number overlap

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-breaking, page-numbering

I have the following problem. I am using the report document class to write my master's thesis. My table of content naturally extends to more than more line, and I have page numbers in the top right corner, except for the first page of each section.

The first page of the table of content does not have a page number (this is correct). The second page and on do have the correct page numbers, except that: on the second page, the page number overlaps on the top entry of the table of content. For example, the first entry in the table of content is:

```
2.6.4 This is the first line on this page........... 29
```

and the page number (iv) appears directly on top of the 29. How can I prevent this from happening? This doesn't happen on the next page, i.e. the v appears above the top entry and the same is true for page vi.

Here's the relevant part of my preamble:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\thepage}

...

\begin{document}

...

\tableofcontents

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your document two-sided?

Comment: What other content do you have in the header? Are you getting any warnings/messages from [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) in your `.log` (something about the header being too big, perhaps)?

Comment: No, my document is not two-sided.

Comment: In my .log file, there's a warning that reads:

    Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt): 
    Make it at least 13.59999pt.
    We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
    This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was missing the line:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
```

in my preamble.